# Using fgets with struct

Tags: c

I get the following error suggestion:

note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'int *'
_CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  char * fgets (char *, int, FILE *);

Which is related to the t->name etc I am guessing, is there any way around this.

Also right now the wins and losses are stored weirdly and the program works like this:

```
inputs:
Name of team > goo
Wins of team > 3
Losses of team > 4
Name of team > goo
Wins of team > 4
Losses of team > 3

outputs
team 1 name is goo

team 2 name is goo
```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_SIZE 20
#define MAXC 1024

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    char wins[MAX_SIZE];
    char losses[MAX_SIZE];
} teams;


int addteam(teams *t);


int addteam(teams *t) {
    char buffer[MAXC];


    printf("Name of team > ");
    fgets(t->name, MAXC, stdin);

    printf("Wins of team > ");
    getchar();
    fgets(t->wins, MAXC, stdin);

    printf("Losses of team > ");
    getchar();
    fgets(t->losses, MAXC, stdin);

    return 0;
}


int main() {
    int numOfTeams;
    char array[MAX_SIZE];
    char * Ptr;

    teams team[MAX_SIZE] = {{ .name = "", .wins = 0, .losses = 0}}; 
    for(int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        addteam( &team[i] );
    }

    for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        printf("team %d name is %s   %s    %s\n",j+1, team[j].name, team[j].wins, team[j].losses);
    }

}
```

Comment: The first arg to `fgets` need to be a char buffer not an int. If you want an int you need to convert it from the string that fgets reads.

Comment: `fgets` reads *strings*.  Strings and only strings.  If you want to read an `int`, you need to do a little bit more.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you don't want `int wins[MAX_SIZE];`.  I think you probably want a single `int` for wins and losses: `int wins;`.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but  you have `fgets(t->name, MAXC, stdin);`  and `char name[MAX_SIZE]` !! Look at `MAXC` vs `MAX_SIZE`. This is a __huge__ source of potential problems.

Comment: @kaylum Do you mean to change the struct variable types into chars, or that I should save the values first into char * arrays and then store them like this teams.wins[i] = arrays, teams.losses[i] = arrays

Comment: @Platopysp not at all.

Comment: What is the `buffer` array for?  What are those extra `getchar()` calls for?

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you that solved everything, I had a thought at one point that the buffer was overflowing and tried to solve it by doing that haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets` reads lines of text into a char buffer. `fgets` knows nothing about numbers.

Replace

```
fgets(t->wins, MAXC, stdin);
```

with

```
char buffer[100];  // temporary buffer for line containing a number
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);  // read line
t->wins = atoi(buffer);                // extract number
```

Do the same for `t->losses`. You probably should put this in a function such as `int ReadIntFromLine(FILE *input)`.

**Disclaimer:**

Instead of `atoi` we could use `strtol` which is a better alternative for real world programs as it allows to detect malformed input.

Comment: Why `sscanf` instead of `atoi` here?

Comment: @SteveSummit why not,? But you're right `atoi` is good enough here and it's more lightweight.

Comment: The main problem is that `scanf` requires you to use `&` during your first few hours or days as a C programmer when you're far, far from really learning about pointers.

Comment: @SteveSummit edited. You're right about the `&`. Many newbies get this wrong with `scanf`, and they also wonder about the fact you need the `&` for `int`s, but not for "strings".

Comment: @Jabberwocky One question, is there a way for me to use the same methods to store name data like fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer),stdin);    t->name = buffer;   Im trying to do this to remove the trailing newline from the name

Comment: No. But you can write something similar yourself based on the information in this question. `fgets` is for reading lines of text, nothing else.

Comment: Should be `strtol`, not `atoi`, so you can detect malformed input.

Comment: @zwol you're right, but here we are dealing with absolute beginner's problems. Malformed input is not yet something he should be too concerned about. Disclaimer added